# White lines in figure after exporting to PDF

Tags: matlab, pdf, export, matlab-figure, vector-graphics

A 2D data matrix was plotted in MATLAB 2016a using `contour` (the first Figure below), and then I saved as the figure in the `*.emf` format. Next, I inserted the figure (`emf`) into a MS word document. And finally, the word document was converted to a `pdf` file.

I found that there are many white lines in the figure (when in a `pdf` format) as shown in the second figure below. My question is how can I remove those white lines?

[image: Figure 1]
[image: Figure 2]

The code is attached here:

```
path = 'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\';
data = importdata([path, 'lsa2.txt'], ' ', 6);
cdata = data.data;
n = 25;
contourf(cdata,n, 'LineStyle', 'none');
colormap(jet);
axis equal;
```

The data can be accessed here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/hzf75qiju6zsy9i/lsa2.txt?dl=0

Comment: This is [a bug in MATLAB](https://www.mathworks.com/support/bugreports/1174438). Although the official bug tracker says it's fixed - it's not. See [this](https://github.com/altmany/export_fig/issues/44) for more details and workarounds (typically using Inkscape for post-processing).

Comment: If the work-around by Dev-iL is too cumbersome, just export as a bitmapped format (PNG or BMP). If you export at 300 dpi, you won’t notice the difference when printed on paper.

Answer (score 4):

As I mentioned in my comment, this is a bug with the way MATLAB exports graphics, as explained by [Yair Altman](https://github.com/altmany/export_fig/issues/44#issuecomment-86748045) and [Dene Farrell](https://github.com/altmany/export_fig/issues/44#issuecomment-267713354):

> *I discovered that these white line artifacts happen when the `painters` renderer is used ... [which] is the default rendering [<s>format</s> engine] for vectorized (EPS/PDF) formats.*

> *There are two separate issues with the Matlab export:*
>
> *1. The main thing that everyone notices is that patches are broken up into triangles, each of which is a separate path object if inspected in illustrator.*
>
> *2. Matlab sometimes adds extraneous 'cropping paths' that create an apparent white line even when there is no issue with fractured paths.*

One workaround suggested there by [ambramson](https://github.com/altmany/export_fig/issues/44#issuecomment-339084805) is the following:

> *1. Save the figure as an `.eps` file (using the `print` command).*
>   *2. Using a text editor, change the line in the eps header from:*
>
> ```
> /f/fill ld
> ```
>
> *to:*
>
> ```
> /f{GS 1 LW S GR fill}bd
> ```
>
> *and move the line down several lines, to right below the `/LW/setlinewidth ld` line.*
>   *From here, your eps file should display fine on all pdf viewers.*

Comment: Thank you. But the processed eps file has destructed the local smoothness of the original figure. I am not sure whether you have noticed this issue.

Comment: @emberbillow Not sure what you mean. [This](https://imgur.com/a/p3VdUja) is what I get after doing the above steps. Could you maybe mark on my image what's wrong compared to your images?

Comment: You figure is just fine, but it is in raster format. You can inspect my result here (https://www.dropbox.com/s/2ulkxd6ww2irtw3/testEPS.eps?dl=0).

Comment: Of course, because it's just a screenshot I took from the [pdf version](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=80746168467730030138). I can see the edges that you mentioned, but I'm not getting them in either the eps or the pdf version. I used [eps2pdf](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/5782-eps2pdf) for the conversion.

Comment: Your result is fine. Can you be a little more detailed about how you get it? I used the following code to save the figure to an eps file: print('testEPS', '-depsc'). Then I used Windows notepad to replace the header line you mentioned.

Comment: That's exactly what I did + called `eps2pdf('fig.eps','fig.pdf',true)` at the end.